# How to execute commands on different CLI from shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I have to connect to a different cli and execute few commands and exit. `sudo $SIGNMCLI` connects to a cli. The below script doesn't work. I want to execute the exit in `SIGNMCLI`.

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

SIGNMCLI=/opt/sign/EABss7024/bin/signmcli

if [ -f "$FileCheck" ];
then
        sudo $SIGNMCLI
        exit;
fi
```

If I do the following, it works:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

SIGNMCLI=/opt/sign/EABss7024/bin/signmcli

if [ -f "$FileCheck" ];
then
        echo 'exit' |sudo  $SIGNMCLI
fi
```

But, I want to execute multiple commands in `SIGNMCLI`. Is there anyway to redirect the control to `SIGNMCLI` and after executing all the commands, the control comes back?

Comment: SIGNMCLI=/opt/sign/EABss7024/bin/signmcli

Answer (score 1):

You can execute multiple commands using semicolon operator in your script.

```
cmd1 ; cmd2 ; cmd3 ...
```

In you case, I suggest you to use ; or &.

```
    echo 'exit'; sudo  $SIGNMCLI
```

This is the basic usage of commands.

```
* A; B    Run A and then B, regardless of success of A
* A && B  Run B if A succeeded
* A || B  Run B if A failed
* A &     Run A in background.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I tried its working.

echo 'ls;ifconfig;who;exit'|sudo $SIGNMCLI

apart from this any other command is there. without using 'echo' command

normally shell script if we are processing any ORACLE request means

we are using >> EOF ....... EOF

same like any commands are there in shell

Comment: Hi, 
i have one more doubt, using shells script i need to continuously checks the directory for particular file, if the particular file is present i need to do some operation.

eg: if file present i need to restart stack 'ss7-stack restart'

Comment: You didnt even upvoted for the provided solution. And now your asking for another shell issue, raise another questions in sf.

Comment: The previous solution is working fine.

if [ -f "$FileCheck" ];
        then
        echo "$FileCheck found entering signmcli command."

        echo '$SIGNMCLI_RESTART;exit' | sudo  $SIGNMCLI

else
        echo "$FileCheck not found." >&2
fi

Comment: If it works fine means you can upvote that's the least courtesy you can do. You can click the mouse button up on little triangle